# iOS UIView background color gets invisible/transparent when adding constraints

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am building a UI where the background color of the main view is black and the background color of some UIView elements within the View are white. The colors get displayed properly when there is not UI constraint for the UIView elements. However, when I add any constraint to the UIView elements, the white background seems to get transparent. I assume that it is still there, since UI constraints of other elements in relative to this UIView element are still on their correct place.

This is the structure of my UI (without UI constraints):

[image]

And this is how it looks like in simulator (iPhone XR 12.2):

[image]

Now I add the following UI constraints to the UIView element **view_config**

[image]

When I run the app in simulator again, now the background color of **view_config** is transparent.

[image]

Comment: Please provide screenshots of your issue so that we could be able to help.

Comment: Hi @SebastianDine, please share more (include constraints) for better explanation.

Comment: Hi, I added some screenshots which should describe my problem in quite some detail.

Comment: In the first screenshot, we can see a red dot in the top right of the left sidebar indicating that there's some constraints missing/conflicting. Maybe you should resolve them and see if that fixes the issue. Hint: click the red icon to see more details on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This solved the problem. The UIView element required a specific height constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a height constraint solved the problem.

[image]

Even better than a static height constraint would be a relative constraint so that
the height of element is calculated implicitly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

is your super view have clear color then change it to black color it will fix your problem